Why are all my connection strings null, when I call builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("connectionString") for my hosted service?
I call options.UseOracle(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("connectionString")) but my connection string is always null. This is within my HostedService.

By default, console apps and things that are set up to run as services don't have the appsettings.json copied into the executable directory at build time. Right click on the appsettings.json and in properties, ensure the json is copied to the output directory and it should be fine.
